# XPath delivering blank text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to pull the text out of a tag that follows an element I'm starting with. The HTML looks like this, with multiple entries of the same structure:

```
<h5>
    <a href="link">Title</a>
</h5>
<div class="author">
    <p>"Author A, Author B"</p>
</div>
<div id="abstract-more#####" class="collapse">
  <p>
    <strong>Abstract:</strong>
    "Text here..."
  </p>
  <p>...</p>
```

So once I've isolated a given title element/node (stored as 'paper'), I want to store the author and abstract text. It works when I use this to get the author:

```
author = paper.find_element_by_xpath("./following::div[contains(@class, 'author')]/p").text
```

But is returning a blank output for 'abstract' when I use this:

```
abstract = paper.find_element_by_xpath("./following::div[contains(@id, 'abstract-more')]/p").text
```

Why does it work fine for the author but not for the abstract? I've tried using `.//` instead of `./` and other slight tweaks but to no avail. I also don't know why it's not giving an error out and saying it can't find the abstract element and is instead just returning a blank...

Comment: There may be other `<p>` elements in the div with empty text. Try this xpath `"./following::div[contains(@id, 'abstract-more')]/p[1]"`

Comment: @JZ115 Which text are you exactly trying to extract `Abstract:` or `Text here...`

Comment: Because the `div` of `Abstract` is  collapsed,  it means the `p` inside it is invisible. 
Selenium will return empty string on invisible element,  like people can't see them, so return empty.  `<div id="abstract-more#####" class="collapse">` , You need to expand the `div` before get text, or call get attribute of `textConect` without expand the `div`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'abstract-more')]/p[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `starts-with` in xpath instead of `contains`.

**XPath:** `.//div[starts-with(@id, 'abstract-more')]/p"`

```
abstract = paper.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[starts-with(@id, 'abstract-more')]/p").text
```

Comment: When I try that it says "No such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: Whether the above mentioned HTML tag is available within the paper element?

Comment: Even if I just take the full driver page and use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'abstract')]/p").text just to get any of the abstract texts, it executes without an error but then returns a blank ' ' instead of text.

Comment: In order to narrow down the issue, please do the below step in Developer Tool(Press F12). Open the Developer tool and then do the search with //div[starts-with(@id, 'abstract')]/p. Please check whether your expected element is getting highlighted in the application and also note down how elements are matched for this xpath

Comment: Yeah when I search that in the Developer tool, it does find the right elements...

Comment: oh...Please check whether you are getting an Abstract: text  for this xpath  //div[starts-with(@id, 'abstract')]/p/strong

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out... the text is behind a button that hides/expands it on screen. So once I added a line to click that button, then it was able to grab it. I think this is why otherwise it was returning blank text. I thought if the xpath was there, it didn't matter what GUI was on screen, but I guess it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath :

```
//div[@class="author"]/following-sibling::div[contains(@id,'abstract-more')]/p[1]
```

in **code** :

```
author = paper.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class="author"]/following-sibling::div[contains(@id,'abstract-more'')]/p[1]")  
print(author.text)
```